# Debugging heapsort

Tags: c, debugging, heapsort

this is my program which works with three functions to perform heapsort.
i m not able to figure out where is the problem in it.
ll be glad if someone ll help.

this two functions calculate left and right of an index

```
int left(int i)
{return(2*i+1);}

int right(int i)
{return(2*i+2);}
```

max here is maximum array index.
a is the array
i is the index

```
void maxheapify(int i,int *a,int max)
{
 if(i>(max-1)/2)
 return;
 else
 {
     int big=0,temp=0;

     if(a[i]<a[left(i)])
     big=left(i);

     if(right(i)<=max && a[i]<a[right(i)])
     big=right(i);

     if(big==i)
     return;

     else
     {
         temp=a[big];
         a[big]=a[i];
         a[i]=temp;
         maxheapify(big,a,max);
     }
 }
 }

void buildmaxheap(int *a,int max)
{
 int i;

 for(i=0;i<=(max-1)/2;i++)
 maxheapify(i,a,max);

}     

void heapsort(int *a,int max)
{
     int j=0,temp=0;

 for(j=max;j>0;j--)
 {
                   buildmaxheap(a,j);
                   temp=a[0];
                   a[0]=a[j];
                   a[j]=temp;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please be more specific with what the problem is, it make a lot less guess work for people who want to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing I am noticing about your code. Your left and right conditions can both be satisfied one right after another. Resulting in the right moving to the parent, but there is no guarantee that right(i) >= left(i). I feel like this might cause some ordering problems after the heap has finished